# SQL Sum() Query error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

## Actual Data

using these queries:

```
Select P.productid, Sum(pr.quantity) AS PQuantity from Products p
join purchases pr on pr.Productid = p.productid
group by p.productid;
```

```
Select P.productid, Sum(s.quantity) AS SQuantity from Products p
join Sales s on s.Productid = p.productid
group by p.productid;
```

This is the content in my tables (Purchases and Sales), the one on the right is the Sum with group by:

[image]

## Problem:

```
select p.productid, sum(pr.quantity) as PQuantity, sum(s.quantity) as SQuantity 
from products p
join sales s on p.productid = s.productid
join purchases pr on p.productid = pr.productid
group by p.productid
```

But the problem arises when I join three tables:

1. products
2. purchases
3. sales

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask]. Look at a few questions as well. Then ***edit and improve*** your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to sum the figures before joining, something like this:

```
select isnull(P.productid, S.productid), P.PQuantity, S.SQuantity
from
(
  Select P.productid, Sum(pr.quantity) AS PQuantity from Products p
  join purchases pr on pr.Productid = p.productid
  group by p.productid
) P
full outer join
(
  Select P.productid, Sum(s.quantity) AS SQuantity from Products p
  join Sales s on s.Productid = p.productid
  group by p.productid
) S on S.productid = P.productid
```